# Хочу удостовериться в правильности выбора числа существительного при двух определениях

Tags: существительные, единственное-множественное-число

Как правильно: на примере "русского и японского языка" или "русского и японского языков"?

Comment: Разница между "языка" и "языков" не в падеже (оба стоят в Р. п.), а в числе (первое слово стоит в ед. ч., второе — во мн. ч.). Заголовок нужно изменить.

Answer (score 1):

> Хочу удостовериться в правильности падежного склонения

Разница между "языка" и "языков" не в падеже (оба стоят в Р. п.), а в числе (первое слово стоит в ед. ч., второе — во мн. ч.)

О таких случаях подробно написано у Розенталя в [§194. Два определения при одном существительном](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/65.htm). Думаю, в данном случае подходит п. 2.

> 2. Имя существительное ставится в форме множественного числа:
>      1)      если подчеркивается наличие нескольких предметов, например: московский и горьковский автозаводы; биологический и химический методы; академическое и массовое издания произведений классиков, широкоэкранный и обычный варианты фильма; марганцевая и хромовая руды; соляная и серная кислоты; кузнечно-прессовый и сборочный цехи; золотая и серебряная медали; гидроэнергетическая и оросительная системы; токарный и фрезерный станки, ходовая и боевая рубки крейсера; овечья и телячья шкуры, разрыв между первым и последним гонщиками, встречи с болгарской и польской футбольными командами; участники гражданской и Великой Отечественной войн

**... на примере русского и японского языков...**

Сравните там же: *в старославянском и древнерусском книжном языке* (перечисляемые разновидности предметов или явлений внутренне связаны).